# How do I change the order of pie chart slices?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics, chart-design

I was wondering if it's possible to change the order of pie chart slices in Adobe Illustrator?

I would like the gray slice to be above the red one.

Changing the order in Graph Data doesn't work and changing it manually (direct selection tool) makes it then impossible to update data and keep the layout.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello Estera, welcome to GDSE, we're glad to have you! You can read the introduction in [help] on how to improve your question and [edit] it accordingly. Feel free to contribute to the site by asking more questions or answering questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select sorting option =None in tool options. You find them when you double click the tool icon in the toolbar.

The order of the produced slice widths can be arbitary if there's no sorting. The colors can be changed with Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork. It doesn't remove the editability of the data.

The colors must be considered to belong to the data cells in the input table. Color order changes if the sorting is done.

This all is taken from a legacy Illustrator, but it should still work.

Sort=None:

[image]

Sort=All:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. You edit your numbers in your data cells, then you need to update the graph by hitting the 'Apply' button as seen below.

Otherwise, your default sorting order may have been changed. Double click the 'Pie Graph Tool' in the menu bar and set the 'Sort' setting to 'None'.

[image]